# Updating MySQL Database with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to send a JS array to a .php file on the click of a button, and run the php file's code on the click, using the array that was sent.

I have a button:

```
<button id="submit" class="button1" >Submit<span></span></button>
```

Which I try to run this JS ajax with:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "submit.php",
    data: selectedImageArray
  }).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
});
```

In my submit.php file, I connect to the database, then have this:

```
    $array = $_POST['selectedImageArray'];

    $sql = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO pending_trades (steam_id, trade_items, is_giving, is_receiving, has_started) VALUES (:steamid, :itemlist, '1', '0', '0')");

    $sql->bindParam(':steamid', $steamprofile['steamid']);
    $sql->bindParam(':itemlist', $array);

    $sql->execute();


}
```

When I click the "submit" button, I get the message saying "Data saved", but nothing is happening with my database. Should clicking the button run the submit.php code?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "nothing is happening"?  Is the AJAX request being made at all?  What is the server's response?  Are there errors on the JavaScript console?  In the PHP logs?  When you debug the JavaScript and/or PHP code, in what way does it fail?  You need to debug your code, we can't do that for you.

Comment: Is that the same code you use or did you write it in the browser just now? Cause the javascript have some issues that should make the script yell error.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error with your JS. Also, since `#submit` is an ID, qualifying it with `button` is unnecessary.

Your code should read:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "submit.php",
    data: selectedImageArray
  }).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
});
```

**Edit 1:**

I see that you have incorporated the above code into your JS. Now on to your problem on the server side (PHP/SQL).

Firstly, why are you decoding `$_POST[selectedImageArray]` then re-encoding it? Doesn't make sense to me.

Secondly, what is the value of `$steamprofile['steamid']`?

Thirdly, what is the schema of your SQL table? Are you sure you're not violating any unique / not null / fk constraint?

Do yourself a favour, and use a debugging/logging solution on the server-side. It can be as simple as printing debug lines into a log file so you can inspect later on to find out what is happening.

What I'd do:

- check value of `$_POST[selectedImageArray]`. It should be a string.
- check the value for `$array`. It should be an array.
- read the error logs to see what else it says.
- `$sql->execute();` returns a `bool` (TRUE on success). Use it in your script to return either success or failure message.
- Log down the value of `$sql->errorCode();` on failure.

With all the above, you should have enough to troubleshoot what went wrong there.

Comment: That made the button work. The `UPDATE` isn't working though, it's not adding any logs into the database.

Comment: With my code, should the code in submit.php get run when I press the button?

Comment: To know why your DB call didn't work, will depend on the SQL table structure, the value you POST-ed (`$_POST[selectedImageArray]`) and other variables like `$steamprofile['steamid']`, or possibly even your `$dbh` - none of which were in the question.

Comment: Well, it did work.. It added one log the first time I tested your code, but now it won't add any more. I also didn't have any items in the array so I couldn't tell if that worked when it added it to the database. I cleared the table in the database so it's empty, still no more data is getting saved..

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "submit.php",
      data: {selectedImageArray: selectedImageArray}, // this is supposed to be JSON
      .done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
      });
  });
});
```

And

```
$_POST['selectedImageArray'] // see the quotes
```

Comment: What does adding the `{selectedImageArray: selectedImageArray}` do? I updated my question just as you posted this sorry. Also, I encode it into a JSON in the submit.php file, are you saying that's wrong?

Comment: can you provide sample `selectedImageArray`. in AJAX call data property expects a json structure to get the access to properties at server end by calling $_POST['selectedImageArray'], means you want value of property `'selectedImageArray'`

Comment: Also at server end access like this `$_POST['selectedImageArray']`, updated the answer with same

Comment: I made the button click also print the array. This is an example of the arrays after Data Saved: http://gyazo.com/1347da743e9ddd06e7a87a6503b0cbd8

Comment: then you have to pass it the way mentioned in above answer and access it the way mentioned in answer. try above changes once and log `$_POST['selectedImageArray'] ` also to see what you are receiving at server

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `steam_id` is a primary key with auto increment, so if you are trying to insert a row to database with the same value for `steam_id`, then it is a possibility that your data cannot be added.

To debug in a better way, try to generate the query in the server and echo it. Then try to run the same query in your MySQL console to find the response.